# If $g\circ f$ is monic, so is $f$

Tags: proof-verification, category-theory

Would anyone mind checking if my proof is ok please?

> If $g\circ f$ is monic, so is $f$.

According to my book (R. Goldblatt's *Topoi*), an arrow $f:a\to b$ in a category $\mathscr C$ is monic if for any parallel pair $g: c\to a$ and $h:c\to a$, $f\circ g=f\circ h$ implies $g=h$.

So we need to show that for any parallel pair $i: c\to a$ and $j:c\to a$, $f\circ i=f\circ j$ implies $i=j$; we start by assuming $f(i(x))=f(j(x))$.

By assumption, we have for all $x$ in $c$, $g(f(i(x)))=g(f(j(x)))$ implies $i(x)=j(x)$.

But since we do have $f(i(x))=f(j(x))$, given the same input $g$ must also give us the same output - hence $g(f(i(x)))=g(f(j(x)))$. This implies $i(x)=j(x)$ - which is exactly what we need.

Comment: You got the right idea by composing $f \circ i$ and $f \circ j$ with $g$, but the notation $f(x)$ does not make sense in a general category. Arrows in a category are not always functions (for example, we could make $\mathbb{N}$ into a category by taking the numbers as objects and an arrow $n \to m$ when $n \leq m$).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As noted in the comments, your use of $(x)$ is mistaken. This is the case because not every category has functions as their morphisms.

---

Here's how a proof should look . . .

> If $f\circ i=f\circ j$, then surely $g\circ (f\circ i)=g\circ (f\circ j)$, so that associativity of $\circ$ gives $$(g\circ f)\circ i=(g\circ f)\circ j,$$  and since $(g\circ f)$ is monic, we have $i=j$. But we started with  $f\circ i=f\circ j$. Hence $f$ is monic.